# Order products by nearest locations

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I want to order products by nearest locations after a location is entered in a search form. I use the Google Maps from ACF to assign location to products and the field is called "address". I have also Google places autocomplete for my form and the ACF google maps radius search plugin. My form redirect to an URL with the lat and lng variables:

`/?s=&post_type=product&lat=43.26768079999999&lng=6.640710899999931`

and the plugin is supposed to order products from this url. The lat and lng are well passed in the URL. Unfortunately it doesn't change anything to the order of the searched products.

Here are some key functions of the plugin:

```
// Join for searching metadata
function acf_google_maps_search_join_to_WPQuery($join) {

    global $wpdb;

    $acf_gms = new acf_gms; 
    $table_name = $acf_gms->table_name();

    if ( 
        isset($_GET['lat']) && !empty($_GET['lat']) 
        && isset( $_GET['lng']) && !empty($_GET['lng']) 
         ) {

        $join .= " LEFT JOIN {$table_name} AS acf_gms_geo ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = acf_gms_geo.post_id ";

    }

    return $join;

}
add_filter('posts_join', 'acf_google_maps_search_join_to_WPQuery');



// ORDER BY DISTANCE
function acf_google_maps_search_orderby_WPQuery($orderby) {


     if ( 
        isset($_GET['lat']) && !empty($_GET['lat']) 
        && isset( $_GET['lng']) && !empty($_GET['lng']) 
         ) {

        $lat = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['lat'] );
        $lng = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['lng'] );

        $orderby = " (POW((acf_gms_geo.lng-{$lng}),2) + POW((acf_gms_geo.lat-{$lat}),2)) ASC";

    }

    return $orderby;

}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'acf_google_maps_search_orderby_WPQuery');
```

and here is the sql query passed to the result page:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_acf_google_map_search_geodata AS acf_gms_geo 
    ON wp_posts.ID = acf_gms_geo.post_id 
WHERE 1=1 
    AND (   
            ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_start’ 
                AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS DATE) > ‘20180122’ 
            )
            AND ( mt1.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_end’ 
                AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) > ‘20180122’ 
            )
            AND ( mt2.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_start’ 
                AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS DATE) <= ‘20180127’ 
            )
        ) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = ‘product’ 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_status = ‘publish’)) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY (POW((acf_gms_geo.lng-6.640710899999931),2) + POW((acf_gms_geo.lat-43.26768079999999),2)) ASC
```

Do you have an idea of the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work !! As woocommerce has its own thing to order products, it was just necessary to write a function like this :

```
if(isset($_GET['lat']) and $_GET['lat'] != "" and isset($_GET['lng']) and $_GET['lng'] != "")
    {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' 

    );
    }
    function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {

    $lat = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['lat'] );
    $lng = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['lng'] );

            $args['orderby'] = ' (POW((acf_gms_geo.lng-{$lng}),2) + POW((acf_gms_geo.lat-

    {$lat}),2))';
            $args['order'] = 'ASC';
            $args['meta_key'] = '';

        return $args;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I identified the problem. I have two meta_query in my functions.php to display products at two different places in my page, according to two different rules.

And the ORDER BY location triggered by the plugin only appears in one of the sql query but not in this one  (although the LEFT JOIN part appears)  :

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )
```

//below you can see that le left join part of the plugin appears

```
LEFT JOIN wp_acf_google_map_search_geodata AS acf_gms_geo ON wp_posts.ID = acf_gms_geo.post_id WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (968) AND (
    wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT object_id
    FROM wp_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (10)
    )
    ) AND (
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = ‘total_sales’
    AND
    (
    (
    ( mt1.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_start’ AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) <= ‘20180125’ )
    AND
    ( mt2.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_end’ AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS DATE) >= ‘20180125’ )
    )
    )
    ) AND wp_posts.post_type = ‘product’ AND (wp_posts.post_status = ‘publish’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘complete’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘paid’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘confirmed’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘unpaid’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘pending-confirmation’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘cancelled’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘private’) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

//but below the order by part of the plugin does not appear

```
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

Do you know how to correct this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this meta_query :

```
$today = current_time('Ymd');
 $args = array (
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'start_clause' => array(
        'key'=>'flash_sale_start',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare'=> '<=',
     'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
         'end_clause' => array(
         'key' => 'flash_sale_end',
     'value' => $today,
         'compare' => '>=',
     'type' => 'DATE'
)

       )
);
return $args;
}

// The main shop and archives meta query
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'custom_product_query_meta_query', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_query_meta_query( $meta_query, $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) 
        return custom_meta_query( $meta_query );
}
```

from which depends the following sql query that doesn't display the orderby location :

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_acf_google_map_search_geodata AS acf_gms_geo ON wp_posts.ID = acf_gms_geo.post_id WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (968) AND (
    wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT object_id
    FROM wp_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (10)
    )
    ) AND (
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = ‘total_sales’
    AND
    (
    (
    ( mt1.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_start’ AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) &lt;= ‘20180125’ )
    AND
    ( mt2.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_end’ AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS DATE) &gt;= ‘20180125’ )
    )
    )
    ) AND wp_posts.post_type = ‘product’ AND (wp_posts.post_status = ‘publish’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘complete’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘paid’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘confirmed’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘unpaid’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘pending-confirmation’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘cancelled’ OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘private’) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

And I have also this meta query :

```
$products = new WP_Query( array (
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => $atts['limit'],
            'meta_query'        => array(
                'relation'      => 'AND',
                'start_clause'  => array(
                    'key'       =>'flash_sale_start',
                    'value'     => $today,
                    'compare'   => '>',
                    'type'      => 'DATE'
                ),
                'end_clause'    => array(
                    'key'       => 'flash_sale_end',
                    'value'     => $today,
                    'compare'   => '>',
                    'type'      => 'DATE'
                ),
        'limit_clause'    => array(
                    'key'       => 'flash_sale_start',
                    'value'     => $limitdate,
                    'compare'   => '<=',
                    'type'      => 'DATE'
                )
)

        ));
}

        ob_start();

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) { ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

            <?php
        } else {
            do_action( "woocommerce_shortcode_products_loop_no_results", $atts );
            echo "<p>Aucune vente &#224; venir pour le moment.</p>";
        }

        woocommerce_reset_loop();
        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }

    add_shortcode( 'upcoming_sales', 'upcoming_sales' );
```

from which depends this sql_query that displays the orderby location trigerred by the plugin :

```
SELECT wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_acf_google_map_search_geodata AS acf_gms_geo 
    ON wp_posts.ID = acf_gms_geo.post_id 
WHERE 1=1 
    AND (   
            ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_start’ 
                AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS DATE) &gt; ‘20180122’ 
            )
            AND ( mt1.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_end’ 
                AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) &gt; ‘20180122’ 
            )
            AND ( mt2.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_start’ 
                AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS DATE) &lt;= ‘20180127’ 
            )
        ) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = ‘product’ 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_status = ‘publish’)) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY (POW((acf_gms_geo.lng-6.640710899999931),2) + POW((acf_gms_geo.lat-43.26768079999999),2)) ASC
```

Do you know why the plugin cannot do the orderby in the first sql query ?